# NoneType object is not callable

Tags: python

Только недавно начал учить python. Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать key-value хранилище. При запуске только с ключом требуется вернуть его значение из файла, если на вход подается ключ и значение то добавить в файл.
Ошибка при попытке запустить с ключом и значением. Подскажите в чем проблема?

```
import sys
import argparse
import os
import tempfile
import json

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--key')
    parser.add_argument('--value')
    return parser


parser = create_parser()
namespace = parser.parse_args()
str = None
if namespace.value is None:
    storage_filename = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
    if os.path.exists('storage.data'):
        with open(storage_filename, 'r') as f:
            json_string = f.readlines()
        parsed_str = json.loads(json_string)
        bool = False
        for arg in parsed_str[namespace.key]:
            str = ", " + arg if bool is True else arg
            bool = True

        print(str)
    else:
        print("File not found")
else:
    storage_filename = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
    if os.path.exists('storage.date'):
        with open(storage_filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write(dict({str(namespace.key): str(namespace.value)}))
    else:
        with open(storage_filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(dict({str(namespace.key): str(namespace.value)}))
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Aleksey>python "C:\Users\Aleksey\playground\Key-value хранилище.py" --key Astrakhan --value 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleksey\playground\Key-value хранилище.py", line 39, in <module>
    f.write(dict({str(namespace.key): str(namespace.value)}))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Вот теперь всё хорошо с оформлением. Ответ insolor пишет, насколько я понял )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Спасибо

Comment: Алексей, а вы дважды сохранили последнюю правку? Не понимаю, чем седьмая версия от шестой отличается: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/716594/revisions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Python нет различия между именами функций (в том числе встроенных) и именами переменных. Поэтому, если вы явно перезаписали `str` значением `None`, то вы уже не сможете вызвать эту функцию под этим именем. Выход - **никогда** (даже если очень хочется) не использовать в качестве имен переменных имена встроенных функций, например `str`, `list` и т.д. Если заменить в вашем коде имя переменной `str`, на любое другое (свободное), то все будет работать нормально.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло.